# rs2xml is not showing the column names retrieved from the database

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using rs2xml to display table retrieved from database
but the problem is. it is not showing the column names retrieved from the database and also the first row is not displayed and the line of code below displays the table results

```
table3.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

it returns the  results below

```
1113    2013-12-04  11000   2000
1115    2012-01-07  8000    2000
```

instead of

```
adm      Date               amount
1113    2013-12-04  11000   2000
1115    2012-01-07  8000    2000
```

Comment: You need to be more detailed about what has happened; in particular give the resulting output. Is there no [rs2xml] tag?

Comment: Without showing us the code you're using to create the JTable, there's not a lot we can do to help you beside guessing at what the problem might be.  I could only reproduce the missing table headers if I explicitly disabled them with `table3.setTableHeader(null);`.  Presumably you're not doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is ever stuck here...

You need to wrap/surround your JTable with a JScrollPane for it to show the table headers...